Java Reactor Flux exception thrown via flatMap can not be handled
I try to handle exception after flatMap (Commented as // Error handler after flatMap). This handler handles only one excetion and then i get [ERROR] (boundedElastic-5) Operator called default onErrorDropped - java.lang.Exception: ER
java.lang.Exception: ER.
AtomicReference<Consumer<String>> onEventListener = new AtomicReference<>();
        var t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                onEventListener.get().accept(Integer.valueOf(i).toString());
            }
        });
        var t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                onEventListener.get().accept(Integer.valueOf(i).toString());
            }
        });
        var f = Flux.<String>create(emitter -> {
                    Consumer<String> al = emitter::next;
                    onEventListener.set(al);

                    System.out.println("Generator initialized!");
                }, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER)
                .groupBy(els -> els)
                .flatMap(els -> els.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                        .concatMap(el -> {
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + el);
                            return Mono.error(new Exception());
                        })
                        .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " INSIDE: " + ex);
                            return Mono.error(new Exception("ER"));
                        }))
                .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " AFTER: " + ex);
                    return Mono.error(new Exception("ER"));
                });


        f.subscribe(s -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Event handled: " + s);
        }, e -> {

        }, () -> {

        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Hello World!");

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        System.out.println("END");

I can handle exception inside flatMap by returning Mono.empty(), but i want to handle excption after flatMap.
There are next solutions:

Returning Mono.empty() inside flatMap
flatMapDelayError insted of flatMap

Is there any way to use flatMap and handle excptions after it?
Output:
Generator initialized!
main Hello World!
boundedElastic-2 : 1
boundedElastic-5 : 4
boundedElastic-3 : 2
boundedElastic-4 : 3
boundedElastic-1 : 0
boundedElastic-1 INSIDE: java.lang.Exception
boundedElastic-5 INSIDE: java.lang.Exception
boundedElastic-4 INSIDE: java.lang.Exception
boundedElastic-2 INSIDE: java.lang.Exception
boundedElastic-3 INSIDE: java.lang.Exception
boundedElastic-1 AFTER: java.lang.Exception:
[ERROR] (boundedElastic-5) Operator called default onErrorDropped - java.lang.Exception: ER
java.lang.Exception: ER
[ERROR] (boundedElastic-4) Operator called default onErrorDropped - java.lang.Exception: ER
java.lang.Exception: ER
[ERROR] (boundedElastic-3) Operator called default onErrorDropped - java.lang.Exception: ER
java.lang.Exception: ER
[ERROR] (boundedElastic-2) Operator called default onErrorDropped - java.lang.Exception: ER
java.lang.Exception: ER
END

